# How to check UDP port listen or not in php?

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I have a service on a server that listen to a UDP port. how can I check my service still listen on this port or not by php?

I think UDP is one-way and don't return anything on create a connection (in fact there is no connection :)) and I should write to a socket.

but, whether I write successfully to a socket or not, I receive 'true'!

my code:

```
if(!$fp = fsockopen('udp://192.168.13.26', 9996, $errno, $errstr, 1)) {
     echo 'false';
} else {
    if(fwrite($fp, 'test')){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

do you have any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should really switch to the [Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) library for creating sockets:

```
$ip = '192.168.13.26';
// create a UDP socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP))) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

// bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $ip, 9996) ) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
```

The only way to see if a socket is still open is to post a message to it, but given the nature of UDP there are no guarantees.

Comment: Edited - I was typing too fast and have been dealing with websockets this morning @duskwuff

Comment: this code only can check socket on the same server! is it right?  is there  a way to check a UDP port on another server?

Comment: That's right. Is the other server broadcasting a message? There is no way to check a remote server to see if the socket is open. You would have to send a message to that server and expect a response from it.

Comment: Thak you, the server doesn't broadcast anything and only listen to port for data.

Comment: You could use `socket_sendto()` to send that server a message, but there is no guarantee of receipt (that is how UDP works). If the remote server does not broadcast or respond there is no way to know if the port is active.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP official documentation said

> fsockopen() returns a file pointer which may be used together with the
>   other file functions (such as fgets(), fgetss(), fwrite(), fclose(),
>   and feof()). If the call fails, it will **return FALSE**

So you can do this to check the error

```
$fp = fsockopen("udp://192.168.13.26", 9996, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    echo fread($fp, 26);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: thank, but i get an error (Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded) when the service listen to port and get nothing when service not listen to port.

Comment: Uh huh ... UDP *is* "one way."  With no guarantees that the message, if dispatched, will ever arrive.

Comment: @MikeRobinson correct UDP does not send acknowledgement

Comment: your code does not work! I think nothing send from server even we write successfully on socket

Comment: Not safe. Official documentation also says 

Warning

UDP sockets will sometimes appear to have opened without an error, even if the remote host is unreachable. The error will only become apparent when you read or write data to/from the socket. The reason for this is because UDP is a "connectionless" protocol, which means that the operating system does not try to establish a link for the socket until it actually needs to send or receive data.